# Centralize objects with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

I'm very beginner with bootstrap. So I ask: is it possible to center the boxes that are inside the div, like the image below?
[image]

My html

```
      <!-- Clientes -->
   <section id="clientes">
       <div class="container">
           <div class="row">
               <div class="section-title text-center wow fadeInUp">
                   <h2>Quem está usando</h2>
                   <p>O SIOM cabe no seu mercado. Tecnologia, Varejo, Cidades...</p>
               </div>
               <div class="linha">
                   <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="background-color:white;padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;">
                       <div class="pricing-table text-center">
                           <div class="price">
                               <img src="img/clients/clientes-ingram.png" alt="Ingram" style="text:center;">
                           </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="background-color:white;padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;">
                       <div class="pricing-table text-center">
                           <div class="price">
                               <img src="img/clients/clientes-parque.png" alt="Parque da Cidade de Brasília" width="120px" height="100px" style="text:center;">
                           </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </section>
```

I do not know if the best practice is to centralize by css. I tried in the bootstrap, but when I make the change I spoiling other parts of the page.

Comment: you mean center them vertically on the y-axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since those two elements are each 3 (of 12) columns wide on medium to large screens, you can add the class `col-md-offset-3` to to first one. This should move both into the middle (creating a 3 columns wide space left of it) - that is, if you haven't used any other CSS besides Bootstrap (which you should have posted, if you did...).